# ORA-00933 Comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Olá, boa tarde

Estou tentando executar seguinte select no TOAD, porem está ocorrendo o erro:
ORA-00933  Comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente

```
SELECT ROWID,
       ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC, 
       ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.SITUACAO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAINICIAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAFINAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAPREVISTA
  FROM ECM_WF_PROC AS ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS,
  LATERAL(SELECT ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.SITUACAO AS SITUACAO, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAINICIAL AS DATAINICIAL, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAFINAL AS DATAFINAL, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAPREVISTA AS DATAPREVISTA
            FROM ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS AS ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS
           WHERE ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.IDEMPRESA = ECM_WF_PROC.IDEMPRESA AND
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.IDWF_PROC = ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC) AS TD_DADOS_ETAPAS
WHERE ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO = '177920'
```

Poderiam me auxiliar como corrigi-lo?

Comment: está executando com F5? já tentou colocar um `;` no final do comando?

Comment: Estou sim, o mesmo erro acontece executando com shift+f9 ou F5.

Comment: com está usando o lateral join ai e só tem campos da tabela "ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS" na subquery, pode remover o alias "TD_DADOS_ETAPAS" e na query principal usar "ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS" no lugar para fazer um teste?

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela atenção Ricardo, estava dando uma pesquisada e o ROWID devo qual tabela deve ser considerada ROW ID. Dessa forma era so acrescentar no select

ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.ROWID